# How to use jsr-310 APIs on Android API level under 26?

Tags: android

I have a jar file that contains POJO classes *(this jar file is used by several modules)*. Some pojo classes use jsr-310's `LocalDate`,`LocalDateTime` etc; but my android application's **min-api** is **(19)**. When I use them as

```
myPojo.setDate(LocalDateTime.now())
```

my andorid-studio shows error as `Calls require API 26 (Current is 19 ....)`

I can't raise my app's API level due to targeted devices but I'd like to use this pojo classes jar file. Has there anyway to achieve it ? Sorry if my question is so stupid.

Comment: You can't. It wasn't added until API 26, so you can't use it on older APIs

Comment: @Zoe Hmm... I thought like this. So, I just asking to make sure it or has anyways to achieve it. I think I have to create same pojo classes with my jar file and I should change Java8's objects to compatible for my app. It is really messy for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), an **Android Backport of JSR-310** that works down to API 15.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android Studio 4.0, you can use various Java 8 language API's like JSR-310 by including the following in your module's build.gradle:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    // Required when setting minSdkVersion to 20 or lower
    multiDexEnabled true
  }

  compileOptions {
    // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}

dependencies {
  coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.5'
}
```